# AdColony with AdMob Mediation. JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, libgdx, admob, adcolony, mobile-ad-mediation

In my Android game, I want to use AdColony with AdMob Mediation. So, I did all by the tutorial: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/adcolony I modified my build.gradle, added Activities, etc. But AdColony ads doesn't work. Here is all that I see in LogCat:

```
09-06 11:20:05.889 14382-14382/com.ogurecapps.box2 I/AdColony [INFO]: Configuring AdColony
09-06 11:20:11.479 14382-14382/com.ogurecapps.box2 E/AdColony: JNI_OnLoad
```

I tryed to google this error, but found nothing. I need some help! My game built on LibGDX engine, for that matter.